# Can I transfer an installation?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm already familiar with transferring Steam games from one hard drive to another, but is this possible to do with Starcraft 2? Starcraft 2 is a huge download and I already have it installed on another hard drive, I was wondering if it would be possible to transfer this one as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A straight copy-paste of the whole installation folder should work.  If you want to copy user-specific data as well, it should be in (My) Documents/Starcraft II.

Blizzard is actually really good about making their installations copy/pastable.  Don't remember about the original Starcraft, but Warcraft III, WoW and SC2 can all be moved by just copy/paste on the whole installation directory.  Any registry stuff is recreated on the new machine if it doesn't already exist (Not sure if it's updated if there's an old installation)

Comment: This is correct, you can just copy over the entire installation folder. For OSX you should check under your Applications\StarCraft II\ folder.    You can't transfer an OSX install to Windows and vice versa unfortunately.

Comment: Oh okay, so the only thing I'll be missing is the registry stuff like you said, which should automatically be generated, and then the start menu stuff right? For that I'd have to manually do a shortcut? Thanks, I'm going to try it then get back to you.

Comment: It worked. I manually added a shortcut to the taskbar. The only thing I notice is that it doesn't show up in the programs list to be able to remove it. I imagine I can just delete the directory, but then it would leave registry residue right? Oh well whatever.

Comment: You could copy the registry entry for the uninstaller on your own. It is located under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. But beware of mistakes!

Comment: Unfortunately the classic Starcraft would not update if you didn't take the registry entries with it. I'm not sure if this is a problem anymore with SC2.

Comment: @Resorath: For future readers: that is no longer the case. Since I've done this, I've updated to 1.2 or whatever the latest big version that came out was. All is fine :)

Comment: You can also copy the battle.net cache, if you don't feel like redownloading all your favorite maps again.  This is located at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Blizzard Entertainment\Battle.net\Cache` in XP, or `C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment\Battle.net\Cache` in Vista/7.

Comment: @Scoregraphic: Not that important, you can simply delete the whole folder to uninstall it