# migrating starcraft 2 from my old laptop to a new computer

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I transfer an installation?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/can-i-transfer-an-installation)

I wonder if there is any way that I can simply copy sc2 with all latest patches to my new computer? There's no doubt that patching from the earliest version to the latest takes very long time. So I am trying to avoid it as much as possible if I could apply all these patches directly to my new computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just copy it.  **Edit:** found dupe http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/14500/6066

Comment: Thanks Matt. That link explains everything I wanted to know. Awesome!

Comment: actaully you can copy the instalation